# static content on a CDN using PHP to get the address

Tags: php, cdn

I'm rather new to PHP programming but I thought I'd do it right from the beginning, so I came across this fine pdf [Web Performance Boot Camp](http://lethargy.org/~jesus/misc/webperformancebootcamp.pdf) where he suggests:

> All sites should *always* prepare for CDNized static content

and this is how:

```
<img src=”<?php echo CDN(‘/i/left-menu-background.gif’) ?>”
```

etc., he also gave an example of how the CDN function? should look like:

```
sub CDN { return @_[1]; }
```

or (when you finally have your static content on a CDN)

```
sub CDN { return ‘http://s.company.net’ . @_[1]; }
```

(but that's not valid php, right? it looks more like perl...)

Anyway, this goes on with how to rewrite the header like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->CDN("c/".$this->css_file) ?>" />
```

But honestly, I have no idea how to do it right. So, my question is, how to I prepare my (php) site for a CDN? Where do I put the sub CDN function? How should it look in valid php? How/Where do I include it? Do I have to put a

```
<?php require('../cdn.php'); ?>
```

at the beginning of every html/php file I create (that uses scripts/css/static images/etc.)? Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're expecting to use a CDN in the future, this is not a stupid idea.

A simple function would look like this:

```
 function getURL($url)  // Name it whatever you want
  {
     // Choose one of the following:
     return $url; // If you're local 
     return "http://s.company.net/".$url; // If you're on a CDN or static server

  }
```

and the markup:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo getURL("c/".$this->css_file) ?>" />
```

> Do I have to put... at the
>   beginning of every html/php file I
>   create (that uses scripts/css/static
>   images/etc.)?

Yes. It might be wise to include some sort of central bootstrap file (some frameworks call it `bootstrap.php`) for future shared PHP settings that you may need to introduce. That bootstrap file would then, in turn, include the `cdn.php`.